# File is corrupted after converting

Tags: javascript, php, recorder.js

I am using `recorder.js` library and want to send the recorded message to my gmail account using `PHPMailer`. I have done everything but the only problem that I am getting is that when I send the file as an attachment and download it from my mail, it is corrupted (or whatever) and my system says `"The file is unplayable"`. Moreover, when I check my local `uploads/` folder where I am writing all the files, they are unplayable too. I don't know what seems to be the problem and I am stuck on this since past two days. Thanks in advance.

My JS call to `upload.php`

```
function sendMessage() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);

        }
    };
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("audio_data", blob, filename);
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

and my `upload.php`

```
<?php
require "php-mailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
$a = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'];
$a = str_replace('data:audio/wav;base64,', '', $a);
$a = str_replace(' ', '+', $a);
$data = base64_decode($a);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.wav';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Please note that I have skipped the part of code which is actually sending mail because I believe that is irrelevant.

Comment: You need to save `$_FILES['tmp_name']`

Comment: @Saf which line?

Comment: Your $data should be `file_get_contents($_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name'])`

Comment: got it. Just one more quick question: My file is storing with some kind of hexadecimal unique name. I want to store my file in this format: YYYYMMDDHHmmss. Can you please tell me how I can do it because if I remove uniqid() function, it gives me error "unable to open stream."

Comment: You can change `uniqueid()` with `date('Ymdhis')`

Comment: @Saf I want "hhmmss" of recorded file showing what is the duration of the recording. Not the system's time.